# How to bind as html parts of a string in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, wysiwyg

I am trying to make a simple **wysiwyg** editor with angularjs. I am making ajax requests with every keyup in a div content editable which is sanitized. So HTML tags are converted into other codes. Now how do I deliberately add styles to it?

Comment: It's unclear until you show how you're doing???

Comment: This is extremely hard to understand. Are you saying you want to display HTML written in the `contenteditble` area in to an output area? This requires string conversion, if that's what you mean. So instead of it being `<div>`, it would need to output in unicode, like  `&lt;div&gt;`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use contenteditable you are actually editing the DOM/HTML node, not just a text representation.
To get the HTML code for an element you can retrieve element.innerHTML.

Try it out here with Chrome: open developer console (F12), select a node, add the contenteditable attribute. Type $0 in the console and you will see the [highlighted] element. Type $0.innerHTML and you will see the code.

Might also be of interest, though it's not really objective: https://medium.com/medium-eng/why-contenteditable-is-terrible-122d8a40e480

Not sure how you are doing sanitation but you should only strip out script tags and leave everything else alone. This will not protect you from all possible XSS attacks as it's a really hard topic and better handled through whitelisting.